# How to prevent prompt that ask to restart services when installing libpq-dev

Tags: debian, software-installation, apt

I want to install `libpq-dev` on my Vagrant machine. I install it with

```
$ apt-get install -y libpq-dev
```

During installation a prompt appears which asks  if it's allowed to restart some services automatically. This prompt breaks my Vagrant provision. How can disable this prompt?

[image: prompt]

Text:

> There are services installed on your system which need to be restarted when
>   certain libraries, such as libpam, libc, and libssl, are upgraded. Since these
>   restarts may cause interruptions of service for the system, you will normally be
>   prompted on each upgrade for the list of services you wish to restart.  You can
>   choose this option to avoid being prompted; instead, all necessary restarts will
>   be done for you automatically so you can avoid being asked questions on each
>   library upgrade.

****EDIT ****

Thanks to [Patrick's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/146341/26992) and [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/227190/how-do-i-ask-apt-get-to-skip-any-interactive-post-install-configuration-steps) question I fixed it. Now my Vagrantfile contains:

```
 sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y libpq-dev
```

Comment: I was suggesting to use `-y` but seems it doesn't change much. see `man apt-get | less +/--force-yes`

Comment: I've tried that optiont too, but that didn't worked either.

Comment: Maybe a bit late, but `-y` is an option for `apt-get`, but the prompt in question comes from `dpkg`, the package management backend used by apt. `DEBIAN_FRONTEND` is read by `dpkg`, that's why it works in this case and `-y` does not.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Set the environment variable `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive`.

For example:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
apt-get install -y libpq-dev
```

This will make `apt-get` select the default options.

Comment: Doesn't work in this case.

Comment: Please specify what "this case" is. The author of the question has selected this answer as correct. If the answer does not work for you, I recommend you ask a new question and make sure to clarify how your case is different, and that this does not work for you.

Comment: It didn't work for me neither.

Comment: Is the default option to restart the service or not restart the service?

Comment: didn't work for me either - 
`export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install -y libssl-dev openssl`. ubuntu 18

Comment: @RSHAP that's because you have exported the `DEBIAN_FRONTEND` variable in your shell, but the executed the commands with `sudo`. This answer describes running the commands as `root`. When using `sudo` you will need to prefix each command with the environment variable, instead of exporting it, e.g. `sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y libssl-dev openssl`

Comment: Is there really no sane way of suppressing a simple (and unnecessary) dialog? If I run a command on CLI, I'll specify what I want. Not via interaction.

Comment: This also didn't work for me. I agree with @JariTurkia

Answer (score 10):

You should be able to achieve this using `debconf-set-selections`. From the man page:

```
debconf-set-selections can be used to pre-seed the debconf database
with answers, or to change answers in the database. Each question will
be marked as seen to prevent debconf from asking the question
interactively.
```

In order to determine the required input to `debconf-set-selections` if unknown, you can answer the prompt manually and then inspect the debconf database to find the correct value. To do this, install `debconf-utils`:

```
sudo apt-get -y install debconf-utils
```

which provides the `debconf-get-selections` command. Then:

```
sudo debconf-get-selections | grep libssl1.0.0:amd64
```

to check the values in the database. On my system (Ubuntu, but Debian should be similar) I am not prompted when I apt-get install libpq-dev, and I have this entry:

```
libssl1.0.0:amd64   libssl1.0.0/restart-services     string
```

so you should be able to use:

```
echo 'libssl1.0.0:amd64 libssl1.0.0/restart-services string' | sudo debconf-set-selections
```

to set the list of services to restart when upgrading libssl to 'none'.

Under Debian, there should be more information about valid values for this line in the `questions.dat` file under `/var/lib/cdebconf`. See https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/apbs03.html.en for more details.

Answer (score 10):

I think the existing answers may be a bit old. The following worked for me recently.

To see the settings for a package

```
sudo debconf-show <package-name>
```

E.G:

```
$ sudo debconf-show libssl1.1 
  libssl1.1/restart-services:
  libssl1.1/restart-failed:
* libraries/restart-without-asking: false
```

To change the setting

```
echo '<package-and-setting-string>' | sudo debconf-set-selections
```

E.G

```
echo 'libssl1.1 libraries/restart-without-asking boolean true' | sudo debconf-set-selections
```

Bonus tip, to set this setting for all packages use '*' in place of the package name.

E.G

```
echo '* libraries/restart-without-asking boolean true' | sudo debconf-set-selections
```

Comment: The accepted answer did not work for me but using `debconf-set-selections` did.

Answer (score 6):

You can disable this feature on Debian 11 by uninstalling the `needrestart` package.

```
apt remove needrestart
```