# How to prevent prompt that asks to restart services when using preseed files

Tags: debian, dialog, preseed

I have set up a custom installation CD based on Debian/Ubuntu. It completely automates the installation apart from asking for the hostname and the system account's password. All was working as expected until just recently when a dialog asking to confirm a restart of services popped up, just like that shown in this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146283). However I'm using preseed files.

I know one could specifically give an answer to that specific package, but it's a fairly generic question that could apply to many other packages and I don't want to have to keep changing the preseed file each time.

Setting `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` on the kernel boot line stopped it alright but also stopped it prompting the user for the hostname and password (which is what I would expect to happen to be honest).

Is there a way of doing the equivalent of `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` and apt-get install -y in a preseed file at a specific point during the installation process so that such dialogs are suppressed from then on in (like after asking the questions and before the main block of packages get installed)?

Comment: Try adding `debconf debconf/frontend        select  Noninteractive` to your preseed file.

Comment: @Christo Thank you for your comment but unfortunately that made no difference. In the end I relented to adding: `d-i libraries/restart-without-asking boolean true` and `d-i libssl1.1/restart-services ssh`, which suppressed the dialog. However the second statement is too specific and so this isn't really an answer, just a work around. Is there a generic way of saying restart any service that needs it?

Comment: @Tony Cooper right now I need to add ```d-i libpam0g/restart-services string cron``` as second option instead of your parameter. Definitely feels brittle.

Answer (score 0):

To sum up on Tony Cooper's comments and the overall change that worked for me:

```
d-i libraries/restart-without-asking boolean true
d-i libpam0g/restart-services string cron
```

are the lines are added and both were needed in order to skip the libpam0g prompt. Too bad there isn't any more general solution as `debconf debconf/frontend select Noninteractive` by itself didn't help.