# How can I install packages silently (without user interaction) with apt?

Tags: apt, vagrant

For a vagrant setup, I want to install xfce4 in the machine. My Vagrant file is based on the box `ubuntu/focal64` (which is a bare minimum system). One of the post-installation steps is:

```
sudo apt install -y xfce4
```

Unfortunately both `gdm3` and `lightdm` are dependencies of `xfce4`. The installer then asks which one to use during installation.

**Is it possible to specify the answers to installation questions so apt runs completely silent?**

Comment: Also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146283/how-to-prevent-prompt-that-ask-to-restart-services-when-installing-libpq-dev, and see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1114525/reconfigure-the-display-manager-non-interactively for debconf for this the default display-manager specifically